# Many to many doesn't store value in database

Tags: hibernate, session, spring-mvc

Hi I have a problem with many to many. I have two classes Taste and Product. At first I created tastes. After that I want to create pruduct and set taste from DB and save this object.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@Entity
public class Taste {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="TASTE_ID")
    private Integer id;
    private String type;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="tastes")
    private List<Product> products;

    public Taste() {
    }


    public Taste(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

second class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Section section;
    private String name;
    private Integer weight;
    private Double baseCost;
    private Double ourCost;
    @ManyToOne
    private Producer producer;
    private String excerciseType;
    private Integer stockCount;
    private boolean inPackage;
    private String description;
    private Integer soldCount;
    private Double score;
    private Integer scoreCount;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="product")
    private List<Comment> comments;
//  @ManyToOne
    @Transient
    private Order order;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    private List<PackageProduct> packageProduct;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_taste" ,joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TASTE_ID", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Taste> tastes;
    private String bigFilePath;
    private String smallFilePath;

    public Product() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public Product(Section section, String name, Double baseCost,
            Double ourCost, Producer producer, String excerciseType,
            Integer stockCount, boolean inPackage, String description,
            Integer soldCount, Double score, Integer scoreCount,
            List<Taste> tastes) {
        this.section = section;
        this.name = name;
        this.baseCost = baseCost;
        this.ourCost = ourCost;
        this.producer = producer;
        this.excerciseType = excerciseType;
        this.stockCount = stockCount;
        this.inPackage = inPackage;
        this.description = description;
        this.soldCount = soldCount;
        this.score = score;
        this.scoreCount = scoreCount;
        this.tastes = tastes;
    }


    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public List<PackageProduct> getPackageProduct() {
        return packageProduct;
    }


    public void setPackageProduct(List<PackageProduct> packageProduct) {
        this.packageProduct = packageProduct;
    }


    public List<Taste> getTastes() {
        return tastes;
    }
    public void setTastes(List<Taste> tastes) {
        this.tastes = tastes;
    }
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Section getSection() {
        return section;
    }
    public void setSection(Section section) {
        this.section = section;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Double getBaseCost() {
        return baseCost;
    }
    public void setBaseCost(Double baseCost) {
        this.baseCost = baseCost;
    }
    public Double getOurCost() {
        return ourCost;
    }
    public void setOurCost(Double ourCost) {
        this.ourCost = ourCost;
    }
    public Producer getProducer() {
        return producer;
    }
    public void setProducer(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }
    public Integer getStockCount() {
        return stockCount;
    }
    public void setStockCount(Integer stockCount) {
        this.stockCount = stockCount;
    }
    public boolean isInPackage() {
        return inPackage;
    }
    public void setInPackage(boolean inPackage) {
        this.inPackage = inPackage;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Integer getSoldCount() {
        return soldCount;
    }
    public void setSoldCount(Integer soldCount) {
        this.soldCount = soldCount;
    }
    public Double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(Double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public Integer getScoreCount() {
        return scoreCount;
    }
    public void setScoreCount(Integer scoreCount) {
        this.scoreCount = scoreCount;
    }


    public String getExcerciseType() {
        return excerciseType;
    }


    public void setExcerciseType(String excerciseType) {
        this.excerciseType = excerciseType;
    }


    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }


    public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    public String getBigFilePath() {
        return bigFilePath;
    }


    public void setBigFilePath(String bigFilePath) {
        this.bigFilePath = bigFilePath;
    }


    public String getSmallFilePath() {
        return smallFilePath;
    }


    public void setSmallFilePath(String smallFilePath) {
        this.smallFilePath = smallFilePath;
    }


}
```

Method from dao, I will get all tastest

```
@Override
    public List<Taste> getAllTastesByIds(List<Integer> ids) {
        Session s = null;
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String hql = "FROM Taste where id IN(:ids)";
        Query query = s.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameterList("ids", ids);
        List<Taste> results = (List<Taste>) query.list();
        s.close();
        return results;
    }
```

After that I want to save my Product

```
@Override
    public void addNewProduct(Product object) {
        Session s = null;
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        s.saveOrUpdate(object);
        s.close();

    }
```

But no record in Database, so when I want to list all product and their taste I cannot get it :(

log from hibernate

> Hibernate: 
>           insert 
>           into
>               Product
>               (baseCost, bigFilePath, description, excerciseType, inPackage, name, ourCost, producer_id, score, scoreCount, section_id,
>   smallFilePath, soldCount, stockCount, weight) 
>           values
>               (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> I tried another why, update Taste and set them all products via

```
@Override
public void updateTaste(Taste object) {
    Session s = null;
    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "UPDATE Taste set type= :type, products = :products where id = :id";
    Query query = s.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("type", object.getType());
    query.setParameterList("products", object.getProducts());
    query.setParameter("id", object.getId());
    query.executeUpdate();
    s.close();

}
```

but I get error

> ```
> Hibernate: 
>     update
>         Taste cross 
>     join
>
>     set
>         type=?,
>         {non-qualified-property-ref}=? 
>     where
>         TASTE_ID=?
> WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07001
> ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - No value specified for parameter 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From preliminary look it looks like it wants data for 'description' field. Can you please confirm that `description` is NOTNULL and that a value is present in it already?

Also if possible please paste in your table setup (indicate the fields and whiche ones are NOTNULL and which ones are NULLABLE).

If the above is not the answer i will investigate for you further.